# How to multithread a button press?

Tags: c++, multithreading, wxwidgets

I have an operation that takes several seconds which is blocking my main thread, which freezes my UI. So, I need to put the operation on a separate thread.

Below mimics what I'm trying to do though obviously doesn't work because `join()` blocks until the thread finishes.

What's the correct approach for allowing the main thread to continue to handle UI events while the button-press thread works on its operation? (C++17, Windows 10, WxWidgets)

```
void OnButtonPress()
{
    std::thread t1 = std::thread( []
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(5000) );
    } );

    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: Create a shared structure to store the result of the thread, when the thread completes populate the shared area then post a custom windows message back to the main UI thread. Don't forget to add some synchronisation.

Comment: How about a thread pool? You can use [this](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool) and add some tasks to this, like: disable the button, run the thing you need, enable the button - assuming enable/disable are thread safe.

Comment: or combine the above with what @RichardCritten suggested

Comment: And what exactly are you using to create UI? Are you using some external library, using WinApi directly?

Comment: push the thread object onto a `vector<thread>` that all get joined at shutdown?

Comment: Knowing what variant of C++ and which OS isn't enough. You're probably using a [GUI _framework_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits). Which framework are you using?

Comment: @SolomonSlow WxWidgets. I'll update the OP

Comment: wxWidgets has primitives for that kind of stuff, and some examples: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/overview_thread.html

Comment: You are talking about a [detached thread](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach). wxWidgets provides also this kind of "fire-and-forget" thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to use threads from a GUI application is to launch the thread and return to the main loop immediately, then post an event when the thread is about to terminate. The handler for this event can join the thread, and you also need to remember to do it on shutdown if the application is closed before the thread has time to terminate.

It is also usually better to keep a background worker thread (or several) running all the time, rather than launching it at button press and communicate with it using messages ([wxMessageQueue](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.5/classwx_message_queue_3_01_t_01_4.html) is a simple class which can be useful for this) telling it what should be done.